# Angular filter doesn't print white spaces

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

When I have such very easy Angular filter code:

```
{{ 'result: ' + array | printArray }}
```

with filter:

```
app.filter('printArray', [
  function() {
    return function(array) {
      if (!angular.isArray(array)) {
        return array;
      }

      var result = '';

      if (array.length > 0) {
        result = array[0];

        for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
          result += ', ' + array[i];
        }
      }
      return result;
    };
  }
]);
```

I would like to have naturally `result: one, two, three, four`, but the result is:

```
abc one,two,three,four
```

I knot it would be resolved by this obvious code:

```
{{ 'result: ' }}{{ array | printArray }}
```

but I would like to know why Angular works in weird way.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/QRtntKedYHKb5UnZD3w7

Comment: I suspect that `'result: ' + array` is being executed before the expression is passed to `printArray` filter, and is triggering the `!angular.isArray(array)` path in the filter. Then what you are seeing is the default Javascript implementation of `array.toString()` being rendered by Angular.

Comment: because "result" + array is not an array it is string. Do  `console.log(typeof array)` in your filter, you'll find the result is `string` instead of `object`.

Comment: Order of operations... And the solution is far simpler and more natural than expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/IOmSwXFQ92i0aeBHvpMy?p=preview)

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  {{ 'result: ' + ( array | printArray ) }}

  </body>
```

Comment: I knew it must have easy solution :)

Answer (score 3):

in this example i used [Array.join()](http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/array/join) function,
and moved the string to outside of the curly braces:

```
result: {{ array | printArray }}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/CRKChEtF5HafdRPV8eW4?p=preview

Comment: Thanks. I rather wanted to have it in one curly braces, but it is also good solution.